# Does any malware target Tails?

Tags: malware, linux

Tails is not a popular OS and is optimized for security, which makes me doubt there is a significant amount of malware that targets it. I googled "malware targeting tails," and found no relevant results.

Comment: What does the tails command do?

Comment: @Micheal it's a privacy focused OS https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tails_(operating_system)

Comment: There will be malware targeting every kind of operating system on the planet, Tails included. A better question to ask would be "What kind of people use Tails, and why would I (as a hacker/attacker) want to target them?". Also possibly relevant: "What kind of entity am I likely to be to target the kind of users Tails attracts?"...

Comment: In addition, Tails is not completely malware/vulnerability-proof either, as seen in https://blog.exodusintel.com/2014/07/23/silverbullets_and_fairytails/. When you additionally consider that certain very powerful entities treat Tails users as high-value targets (see http://www.computerworld.com/article/2863937/snowden-docs-show-tor-truecrypt-tails-topped-nsas-most-wanted-list-in-12.html), expecting no malware to target Tails is most likely wishful thinking.

Comment: @Nasrus Really? Do you know of any specific malware strains that infect Tails?

Comment: To the extent of my limited knowledge, in the public domain, as of the time I write this comment? A qualified no. But, do remember the kinds of entities that would target Tails users as mentioned above, and why they might not want their Tails-targeting malware published...

Comment: I remember reading somewhere about malware created for governments which can target Tails.

Comment: There's that Zerodium bug bounty on Tails, but that's looking for exploits rather than _malware_ per se. It shows that it is certainly possible, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does *any* malware target Tails? The most literal answer has to be yes, because I have written malware for Tails (it requires manual installation as root, but it is still *technically* malware). I'm sure other people have as well. I have not come across any malware targeted specifically for Tails in the wild, though.

You also have to take into account the fact that Tails is just highly customized Debian, which itself is just GNU/Linux, so the question becomes "Is there any malware which targets GNU/Linux, which is compatible with Tails out of the box?". For example, the "torsploit" attack which exploited an outdated version of Tor Browser may have been able to attack Tails, however the Tails firewall was able to block it. It simply was not compatible with Tails, because it was designed for a generic system without all of the protections Tails had in place. Does this mean that this malware hit Tails? Yes. Does it mean it succeeded in its goal to call home and deanonymize the user? No.

In general, there will likely be little general-purpose malware which is effective against Tails. If you are foolish enough to run a Perl botnet script, you may see your Tails machine connecting to a malicious IRC network to participate in a DDoS. However, it is still possible to target malware toward Tails. The attacker may have to chain a number of 0days, or may have to exploit a number of known bugs in a clever way, but it's certainly possible.

My educated guess is **yes**, there is malware designed by state-level adversaries which specifically targets Tails, most likely deployed in combination with a warrant and used sparingly against high value targets. Most likely it involves either social engineering, or targeting outdated versions of the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris already stated, you must think about the intents of malware authors and how the malware is spread.

Spreading a malware is a difficult task because you need either an exploit which works with a software the targets are using to view untrusted content or users which are inexperienced enough to follow certain instructions to help with the infection. Linux in general and Tails in particular is more difficult to attack since there are certain security measures you must overcome for a successful infection. Further you can assume that most users of Tails are experienced and kind of "paranoid" so they will not fall for simple, not targeted social engineering.

Lets have a look at the intents of modern attackers.

#### Making Money

This represents the 99% of attackers. This involves attacks like banking or other account data gathering spyware and ransomware. Again, a live boot system is pretty much senseless target platform since you can not have persistence so you must be lucky enough that the target will input or query some sensitive data after the infection. For ransomware you must either run as root to search for other storage devices (and hope they are not encrypted) or you are lucky and the target has mounted some. It's important to this kind of attackers that they make more money than they invest - it must be profitable.

#### Spy on particular targets

If you are important enough, someone will try to somehow spy on you. Most of this kind of attackers have enough money and other resources so it's improbable that you can do anything about it just by using Tails. They will find a way.

TL/DR;

With Tails you are not the target of casual broadband attacks for profit at the moment. This could change, if the Linux desktop market share massively increases. Attackers with a political or "high level" economical motivation [might find you very interesting](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/07/nsa_targets_pri.html) though.

Comment: "Again, a live boot system is pretty much senseless target platform since you can not have persistence..." You actually [can](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/index.en.html) have persistent volumes on Tails, but as far as I know you cannot have programs persist.

Answer (score -1):

There aren't many. And that is not only for Tails. The malwares designed for linux are rarely found, because: 
1. It's more difficult to create them (compared to windows)
2. There aren't many everyday users working on linux. So, when someone creates a malware hoping to spread it throughout the net, he will make it for windows.
That leaves us with the linux servers, where (almost) all designed malware targets.

Comment: To clarify, most Linux attacks are based on the idea of attacking server software, like a web server or file server, either to gain elevated access to get to valuable data, or to cause a denial of service. As Tails world be running on a workstation without server processes and without valuable data, it's not an appealing target.